# How to Use Audience Network System User Token

Tags: php, curl, facebook-instant-articles

I've read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api#accessforpublishers) and successfully getting report using Short Term User token. The problem is the token not lasting. So i tried using [System User Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api/systemuser) but getting error as below:

```
"message": "(#3000) Reading Insights of a Page/App/Domain/Event Source Group 
not owned by the querying user or application",
```

I've set the permission via business manager to the user, and try to access directly without problem.

This is what i tried on graph api tool v3.0:

```
app_id/adnetworkanalytics/?metrics=['fb_ad_network_imp']
```

The objective is to make reporting available to employee's with only specific data view via website. For example:

```
Today Impressions: XXXX
Yesterday Impressions: XXXX
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: hi guys, no help on this? Or i need to explain more on my question?

Comment: No this is a completely valid question and I also find myself in the same position, with no clear way to do it. It seems FB is forcing yet another API on devs without it being ready for production.

Comment: Have u got any solution?